# React javascript: SetState() is not forcing a re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm returning an empty div until my socket connection is done, and i got the data from it.
But setState never forces a re-render, why and how do I fix it?

Check LoadData() and Render()

````
class LoadNames extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {names: []}
        this.loaded = false;

        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    }   

    componentDidMount()
    {
       this.loadData();
    }

    loadData()
    {
        socket.on("updateCatagories", (data) => {
            //entry point
            console.log("UPDATE RECIEVED, NEW DATA: ");
            this.loaded = true;
            this.setState((state, props) =>
            {
                this.names = data              
            })
           
            console.log(this.names);
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log(this.loaded);
        if (this.loaded === false)
        {
            return <div />
        }

        return <h1>here: {this.state.names[3].name}</h1>
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the state correctly.

You need to return the object literal from the callback function passed to `this.setState(...)`

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({ names: data }));
```

In your case, since new state is independent of the previous value of the state, you could update the state as shown below:

```
this.setState({ names: data });
```

---

**Side note:** You are logging `this.names` (it should be `this.state.names`) immediately after calling `this.setState()` but state is updated asynchronously, so it won't log the new value of `this.state.names`.

To log the updated value of state, you could pass second argument to `this.setState()` that is a callback function which is called after the state has been updated.

```
this.setState({ names: data }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.names)
});
```